# Creating a Reminder Email in Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, reminder

I have a SPD workflow that starts when a new list item is created. It sends an email notification to the first Reviewer and then I have it set to "Wait for field change in current item."

I need to setup an email reminder that would loop and repeat every 3 days.
I read about maybe setting up a calculated column for a "Reminder Date" `=[created]+3` and then I would need an Action like `If [Reminder Date] >= [Today], then Send an e-mail to Reviewer 1`

I don't think this would work because the workflow would see that this condition does not apply and then move on to the "Wait" step which holds up the workflow.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Create Site workflow and check the items in the target list, then based on the status of the item you can send reminder to users. In Site workflow you need to pause the workflow for 3 days and send to same stage so that site workflow sends email for every 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a Parallel block. Using a parallel block, one side can have the wait for item change event while the other handles your reminders. In this scenario, the reminders will continue without the workflow being stopped by the wait for item change event.

I haven't tried it with the wait for field change, but have done this with task completion, and sending out reminders, so this should work as well.

Comment: I currently have a parallel block running for my Wait step. It is immediately after an email notification is sent to the Reviewer. It looks for the Approve/Reject field to be completed before moving on with the workflow.
Could I use another parallel block with this? And what action would you recommend I use for the reminders?